# Welche Funktion hat der Genitiv hier?

Tags: genitive

Welche Funktion hat der Genitiv in "der Alltag vieler Menschen"?

Fällt dieser Genitiv unter den possessiven Gebrauch, obwohl man den Alltag nicht besitzt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na ja, ich besitze meinen Alltag schon, in dem Sinne, dass nur ich ihn habe, sonst niemand. Schon im Lateinischen hat *possedere* diese ungegenständliche Bedeutung: *possedit favorem plebis Clodius* "Clodius hat den Zuspruch des Volkes" (Ovid). Insofern meint "possessiv" nicht nur physischen Besitz, sondern auch ideellen. Anders gesagt, der Genitiv in "der Alltag vieler Menschen" drückt einen Besitz aus.

Beispiele für *genitivus possessivus* im Lateinischen, in denen kein Besitz ausgedrückt wird:

- *patria Marci Tullii* "die Heimat des M. Tullius" (Marcus besitzt seine Heimat nicht)
- *natura loci* "die Beschaffenheit des Ortes" (der Ort besitzt seine Beschaffenheit nicht)
- *Hoc vitium est proprium discipulorum.* "Dieser Fehler ist typisch für Schüler." (die Schüler besitzen den Fehler nicht
- *meum vestrum est* "es ist meine Pflicht" (ich besitze die Pflicht nicht)

Comment: Einen Alltag 'haben' erscheint mir eine etwas eigenwillige Betrachtungsweise zu sein. Die so genannte possessive Funktion lässt sich viel genereller - und m.E. auch zutreffender - als eine Verknüpfung oder Zuordnung beschreiben, die nebenbei bemerkt auch identifizierend (= determinierend) wirkt: Von welchem Alltag sprechen wir hier, von deinem oder von meinem? - Weder noch, nur allgemein vom Alltag vieler Menschen. Dass sich derartige Zuordnungen in vielen Sprachen mit 'haben' ausdrücken lassen, ist gewissermaßen zufällig; ich hab mir sagen lassen, im Arabischen sei das nicht so.

Answer (score 2):

Ja, die *possessive* Funktion drückt regelmäßig auch bloße Assoziation, Einbettung etc. aus. Sie ist ebensowenig auf wahren *Besitz* beschränkt wie etwa der *Akkusativ* auf das *Anklagen*. Die ursprüngliche lateinische Bedeutung ist also heute irreführend.

Comment: Die ursprüngliche lateinische Bedeutung ist ebenfalls nicht auf physische Besitztümer beschränkt. Siehe meine Antwort. Inforern ist die lateinische Bezeichnung keineswegs irreführend.

Answer (score 2):

'Possessiv' ist eine irreführende Bezeichnung für eine Zuordnungsbeziehung. In

> ***mein** Alltag hat sich mit dem Baby sehr verändert*

ist das traditionell als Possessivpronomen bezeichnete *mein* weder possessiv (besitz-bezeichnend) noch ein Pronomen ('Stellvertreterwort' für ein Nomen, denn das Nomen *Alltag* ist ja noch da). Das korrespondierende Pronomen gibt es in

> *Welches Auto nehmen wir heute?* - **Meins**.

Aus Vereinfachungsgründen wird an der Bezeichnung 'possessiv' in den Grammatiken fast durchgängig festgehalten, denn die tatsächlich possessive Bedeutung der entsprechenden Artikel(wörter) / Determinanten / Begleiter und Pronomen und Genitive schiebt sich wie selbstverständlich sofort ins Bewusstsein, wenn man diese Wörter und Konstruktionen benutzt. Als kleine Kinder haben wir wahrscheinlich schon im Sandkasten gelernt, was '*mein Förmchen*' ist und was passiert, wenn ich dem anderen '*sein Förmchen*' wegnehme.

In gewisser Hinsicht ist die Bezeichnung *possessiv* für die andern Verwendungsweisen von Possessiva, die Hubert Schölnast nennt, metaphorisch: In jedem Fall stehen die possessiv angebundenen Wörter in einem engen inhaltlichen Bezug zu ihrem grammatischen Bezugswort.

Comment: "Possessiv" ist nicht irreführend, da *possedere* im Latenischen nicht nur physischen Besitz ausdrückt. Siehe meine Antwort.

Comment: es ist mindestens im Sinne von Sapir-Whorf doch durchaus possessiv. Wer seinen Alltag nicht im Griff hat, kann gleich gar nicht von Alltag die Rede sein. Insofern *possess-* auch auf *potis* "master" zurück geführt wird, macht das um so mehr Sinn. Grammatisch ist "vieler Menschen" in gewissem Sinne vielleicht dem nominative nomen untergeordnet, sowie der Mensch eventuel tatsächlich ein Produkt seiner Umgebung sein mag. Tatsächlich steht der Mensch aber eigentlich immer im Mittelpunkt. Der Genetiv wird nicht metaphorisch schon weil etwa "Alltag" eine Metapher ist.

Answer (score 0):

In der Phrase *»der Alltag vieler Menschen«* liegt ein *Genitivus explicativus* (Genitiv der Erklärung) vor.

*»Genitiv«* ist der Name einer Klasse bestimmter grammatischer Konstruktionen (Genitivattribut als Links- oder Rechtsattribut, Genitivobjekt), diese Konstruktionen können aber für unterschiedliche Zwecke eingesetzt werden.

Der Genitiv wird für diese Zwecke eingesetzt:

- **Genitivus possessivus** = besitzanzeigender Genitiv
  Ein Attribut im Genitiv zeigt den Besitzer einer Sache an.

  > das Haus *des Bürgermeisters*
  > *Ottos* Schuhe
- **Genitivus auctoris** = Genitiv des Urhebers
  Das Genitivattribut gibt den Namen des Urhebers eines Werkes wieder.

  > *Beethovens* neunte Symphonie
  > *Christines* Dissertation
- **Genitivus qualitatis** = Genitiv der Beschaffenheit
  Das Genitivattribut drückt eine besondere Qualität aus.

  > ein Ticket *zweiter Klasse*
  > eine Frau *jüngeren Alters*
- **Genitivus totius** = Genitiv der Ganzheit
  Das Genitivattribut gibt ein Ganzes wieder, von dem ein Teil genommen wird.

  > die Hälfte *des Kuchens*
  > Die Mehrheit *der Wähler*
- **Genitivus partitivus** = Genitiv des Anteils
  Synonym für *genitivus totius.* Der Name *»genitivus partitivus«* wird zwar häufiger verwendet, ist aber irreführend, weil das Genitivattribut nicht den Teil sondern das Ganze wiedergibt.

  > der Norden *des Kontinents*
  > der älteste Sohn *der Familie*
- **Genitivus subiectivus** = Genitiv der Quelle einer Handlung
  Das Genitivattribut drückt aus, wer etwas verursacht hat

  > der Rat *eines Freundes*
  > Das Denken *des Menschen*
- **Genitivus obiectivus** = Genitiv des Ziels einer Handlung
  Das Genitivattribut drückt aus, wer von der Handlung betroffen ist

  > die Bestrafung *des Diebs*
  > die Zerlegung *des Motors*
- **Genitivus explicativus** = Genitiv der Erklärung
  Das Genitivattribut macht nähere Angaben über etwas

  > Die Quelle *der Hoffnung*
  > Der Sinn *des Lebens*
- **Genitivus definitivus** = Genitiv der Begriffsbestimmung
  Das Genitivattribut legt die Art und Weise von etwas fest. Weil der *Genitivus definitivus* kaum vom *Genitivus explicativus* zu unterscheiden ist, werden beide Begriffe meist synonym verwendet.

  > Das Laster *der Trunksucht*
  > Das Verbrechen *des Mordes*
- **Genitivus hebraicus** = paronomastischer Intensitätsgenitiv
  Das Genitivattribut drückt eine Steigerung aus (Synonym: *Genitivus superlativus*)

  > das Buch *der Bücher*
  > der König *der Könige*
- **Genitivus criminis** = Genitiv des Verbrechens
  Das Genitivobjekt gibt ein Verbrechen wieder

  > Ludwig wird *des Mordes* bezichtigt.
  > Irene wird *der Helerei* verdächtigt.

Comment: In "der Alltag vieler Menschen" macht das Genitivattribut aber keine genaueren Angaben über den Alltag. Wir erfahren dadurch nicht, auf welche Weise sich dieser Alltag von anderem Alltag unterscheidet. Genitivus explicativus wäre sowas wie "der Alltag des Arztberufs". Hier entsteht durch den Genitiv unmittelbar eine Vorstellung von der Art des Alltags.

Comment: Der _Genitivus criminis_ schert aus der Reihe aus; er ist ein Objektkasus (Genitivobjakt), die anderen sind Attribute, die sich teilweise einer Apposition annähern [so der Genitivus definitivus: Statt _das Verbrechen des Mordes_ könnte man auch sagen _das Verbrechen Mord (wird in den meisten Ländern als eine der schwersten Straftaten geahndet)].

Answer (score 0):

Ob

> a) "Der Alltag vieler Menschen ist (zu hektisch)"

oder

> b) "Der Alltag ist vielen Menschen (zu unübersichtlich)"

macht nur einen geringen Unterschied. Regiert wird der Fall im Beispiel nicht.

> c) "Der Menschen Alltag"

ist theoretisch auch zulässig (vgl. "Der Mode letzter Schrei") und verdeutlicht anschaulich dass Mensch eigentlich vordergründig so wie nominativ steht.

Dar in (c) noch die Quantität "viel" unterzubringen ist durch einfache Umformung der Wortfolge (a) nicht zu erreichen.

> d) Vieler Menschen Alltag

verdeutlicht, dass *viel* eigentlich Determinativ ist.

Da Alltag unzählbar ist, bleibt offen, ob jeder seinen eigenen Anteil besitzt, Ihn sich teilen muss, oder ob, sofern "Alltag" als grammatisches Subjekt erkannt wird, etwa "Vieler Menschen" Attribut ist und dieses "vieler" wie bspw. "voller" (*ein Käfig voller Helden*) sein möge; eigentlich Präposition, die Aktionsart (Aspekt des Verbs).

Erschwerend kommt hinzu, dass auch prinzipiel zählbare nomina in ähnlich gearteten Phrasen unzählbar verwendet werden (*das Gehalt vieler Menschen*, oder *die Gehälter*), da nämlich many-to-many Relationen in der deutschen Grundsprache so nicht vorgesehen sind, so dass die Besitzanzeige regelmäßig offen bleibt und aus dem Kontext erschlossen werden muss (*die Nebeneinkünfte von Politikern*). Die Obermenge, die Summe aller Einzelteile, wird auf der syntaktischen Ebene unspezifisch, beliebig verteilbar.

Deine Frage wäre also im Ergebnis pragmatisch allenfalls philosophisch zu handhaben, aber nicht hier.

Comment: Das Determinativ von Alltag ist, wenn man so will, nicht 'vieler', sondern 'vieler Menschen'. Allerdings ist es unüblich, das als Determinativ zu bezeichnen. Es hat jedoch determinierende Funktion: _Von welchem Alltag reden wir hier eigentlich genau?_ Aber innerhalb der Gruppe 'vieler Menschen' ist in der Tat 'vieler' der Determinant: nicht _aller_, nicht _mancher_, nicht _der meisten_, nicht _einiger_, sondern _vieler_, ein Determinant mit quantifizierender Funktion; das kennen wir ja schon vom unbestimmten Artikel.